# unable to connect to Kubernetes: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials

Tags: kubernetes, goland, skaffold

skaffold version
v1.35.1

Using [local registry:2](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/local-registry/) in KinD cluster.

`kubectl config current-context` > kind-kind. And kubectl config view, shows the right url for `kind-kind` to the server: 127.0.0.1:57836

#### Expected behavior

In Goland: Cloud Code: Kubernetes - a running example

skaffold.yaml

```
# To learn more about the skaffold.yaml schema visit
# https://skaffold.dev/docs/references/yaml/
apiVersion: skaffold/v2beta19
kind: Config
build:
  artifacts:
  - context: .
    image: go-hello-world
deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests:
    - kubernetes-manifests/**
```

#### Actual behavior

Error:

```
unable to connect to Kubernetes: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials
```

Note in the following, that it actually runs - but only very short time. See: `Step 8/14` in the following

skaffold dev --default-repo localhost:5000

```
Listing files to watch...
 - go-hello-world
Generating tags...
 - go-hello-world -> 127.0.0.1:5000/go-hello-world:6b3fc6f-dirty
Checking cache...
 - go-hello-world: Not found. Building
Starting build...
Found [kind-kind] context, using local docker daemon.
Building [go-hello-world]...
Sending build context to Docker daemon  932.9kB
Step 1/14 : FROM golang:1.16 as build
 ---> 5b838b7289de
Step 2/14 : WORKDIR /hello-world
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a8c93bc46b78
Step 3/14 : COPY go.mod go.sum ./
 ---> Using cache
 ---> cba8d38c5d62
Step 4/14 : RUN go mod download
 ---> Using cache
 ---> bfb3c3842a45
Step 5/14 : COPY . ./
 ---> f7f0547858d2
Step 6/14 : ARG SKAFFOLD_GO_GCFLAGS
 ---> Running in 8df9562291c8
 ---> 20aec50f0a84
Step 7/14 : RUN echo "Go gcflags: ${SKAFFOLD_GO_GCFLAGS}"
 ---> Running in f35f8060867a
Go gcflags: 
 ---> cc2532367c46
Step 8/14 : RUN go build -gcflags="${SKAFFOLD_GO_GCFLAGS}" -mod=readonly -v -o /app
 ---> Running in 03fe6cd6a195
hello-world
 ---> d8873c3d1844
Step 9/14 : FROM gcr.io/distroless/base
 ---> 64bbfbb81976
Step 10/14 : ENV GOTRACEBACK=single
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e7db9a53c2fe
Step 11/14 : WORKDIR /hello-world
 ---> Using cache
 ---> cba82d8b0927
Step 12/14 : COPY --from=build /app .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> fdd46a287814
Step 13/14 : COPY template ./template
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 01f1804abfcc
Step 14/14 : ENTRYPOINT ["./app"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c57d404bd28f
Successfully built c57d404bd28f
Successfully tagged 127.0.0.1:5000/go-hello-world:6b3fc6f-dirty
Tags used in deployment:
 - go-hello-world -> 127.0.0.1:5000/go-hello-world:c57d404bd28fbee71266d45debb822dd57215b585c2e16f5b1b21b5632ee0904
Starting deploy...
Cleaning up...
unable to connect to Kubernetes: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials
```

Comment: This seems like your kubeconfig is missing or invalid.
Does `kubectl config current-context` give any output?

Comment: Yes, it shows: kubectl config current-context > kind-kind. And  kubectl config view, shows the right url to the server: https://127.0.0.1:57836

Comment: Thanks, and it also actually runs for very short time before: unable to connect to Kubernetes: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials

Comment: It runs just after: Step 8/14

Comment: Could you try to explicitly define your kubeconfig when calling skaffold. Like so:
`skaffold dev --default-repo localhost:5000 --kubeconfig <path to kubeconfig>`

If that doesn't work maybe try excuting skaffold with the `-v debug`  flag to provide some debugging output.

Comment: Wau, that actually worked. Hmm, thanks - strange :-) I can port-forward to the pod. Let me accept an answer

Comment: Does `kubectl --context kind-kind get all` work?  If not, then it sounds like you might have stale credentials in your `~/.kube/config` or the config files defined in `$KUBECONFIG`.

Comment: Yes, it does work - thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running skaffold with the `--kubeconfig <path to kubeconfig file>` should to the trick.